# mongodb docker - connection refused

Tags: mongodb, docker

So I've been having some issue setting up mongodb in docker. I can't even connect to mongoDB compass.
Here is my docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: '3.0'

services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        environment:
           MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
           MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        ports:
        - 27017:27017
        volumes:
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodbdata/_data
```

I used `docker-compose up --build`, and everything seems to be working just fine.
Now when I try to connect to mongoDB compass with :

```
mongodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017
```

I get the following error : ***connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017***

So I tried to check if the mongodb server was running and correctly listening to port 27017 with `netstat -an | grep 27017` but I don't have any output here. What's the issue here I'm kinda lost. Because in the terminal I used to run `docker-compose up --build` it says that it's waiting for connection on port 27017

Comment: That `volumes` section is incorrect. If you remove it, do things work? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You may want to review the [volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).